# Download Mode. What does this mean?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5, odin

RP SWREV B:3 K:0 S1

Searching online, I haven't found any clear information.

Comment: Is your phone bricked? Doea it not pass the logo screen?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you just curious about what download mode is for? Did you get into download mode by accident? Does your phone boot in download mode every time you turn it on?

Answer (score 2):

**download mode** is related to recovery where your device is ready to accept a new system image from the computer.

It is used to flash a new OS to the device.

In download mode, you can inject and install the OS (flashing).

**but be careful while using this**

Comment: I meant what does this line in download mode means RP SWREV B:3 K:0 S1

Comment: @Kenny it apparantly is the software revision installed on your device.